# UITest with Jenkins failed for Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=-1 "Could not locate installed application"

Tags: ios, jenkins, uitest

When I do UI test with Jenkins，it failed with Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=-1 "Could not locate installed application".

The detail log is :

```
Details:  Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = com.apple.test.iOS-3DTouchUITests-Runner
Object:   <DVTiOSDevice: 0x7faafda80610>
Method:   -installForMobileInstallWithSession:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faafd086dd0>{number = 9, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2017-01-19 19:35:38.382 xcodebuild[59624:934106] Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=-1 "Could not locate installed application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not locate installed application, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Install claimed to have succeeded, but application could not be found on device. bundleId = com.apple.test.iOS-3DTouchUITests-Runner}
2017-01-19 19:35:38.382 xcodebuild[59624:934106] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}

Testing failed:
    Test target iOS-3DTouchUITests encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted)
** TEST FAILED **
```

But when I do the ui test directly with Xcode, everything is OK.

Anyone can help me with this ?